# Instead of left click on a link I find I must right click. Why? Is this a new feature or a bit of code that went wrong?

Tags: frontend, web-frontend

I am facing an issue with slider button link, when I right-click on button it's working fine but not on left-click. I have tried many things, yet do not find any solution.
here is button code:

```html
<a class="wow bounceInUp" data-wow-offset="10" href="https://www.google.com" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: bounceInUp;">Shop Now</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put your button code into a codepen. It does seem to work for me. make sure to start and end your button with `<a> </a>`

`<a class="wow bounceInUp" data-wow-offset="10" href="https://www.google.com" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: bounceInUp;">Shop Now</a>`

https://codepen.io/Leeroy-J/pen/podVRvy

Comment: http://qibla-design.com/ please check this slider button text as shop now